# How to instantly append named values to a data frame based on it's corresponding name?

Tags: r, dataframe, append

I have a dataframe that has 6 columns

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6
   1    3    4 r1   r2   5
   5    3    2 s1   s2   5   
   5    4    2 x1   s2   5
```

Then I have 6 values

```
col1<-4
col2<-2
col3<-1
col4<-"f1"  
col5<-"s1"
col6<-7
```

How do I append those values into the dataframe based on its corresponding name so that I have

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6
   1    3    4 r1   r2   5
   5    3    2 s1   s2   5   
   5    4    2 x1   s2   5 
   4    2    1 f1   s1   7
```

Comment: You say "corresponding name", but all of the names are different (R is case-sensitive). If you instead mean `Col1<-4;Col2<-2;...`, then simply `rbind(dataframe, data.frame(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6))`.

Comment: But be careful ... iteratively adding rows to a frame using `rbind(old, newrow)` works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). For each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`.

Comment: i adjusted the case. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure your environment only contains variables you want, you can use `ls` with `as.name`

```
col1<-4
col2<-2
col3<-1
col4<-"f1"  
col5<-"s1"
col6<-7

rbind(dat, data.frame(sapply(ls(pattern="col[1-6]"), as.name)))
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
1    1    3    4   r1   r2    5
2    5    3    2   s1   s2    5
3    5    4    2   x1   s2    5
4    4    2    1   f1   s1    7
```

##### Data

```
dat <- structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 5L, 5L), col2 = c(3L, 3L, 4L), col3 = c(4L, 
2L, 2L), col4 = c("r1", "s1", "x1"), col5 = c("r2", "s2", "s2"
), col6 = c(5L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```